# MySQL MAX returning null even though there is a value available

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I'm working on a MySQL 5.7 database, and I'm having some trouble with a somewhat big query I made recently, digging a little deep in it, I found out that a specific section wasn't running as expected. I did some testing and found something weird going on.

The section is as follows (the numbers had to be hard coded for the specific scenario, but usually its values from another table):

```
SELECT
    MAX(cp.dataAtualizacao) dataAtualizacao,
    MAX(m.dataRegistro) dataRegistro,
    CASE WHEN MAX(cp.dataAtualizacao) > MAX(COALESCE (m.dataRegistro, cp.dataAtualizacao)) THEN MAX(cp.dataAtualizacao) ELSE MAX(COALESCE (m.dataRegistro, cp.dataAtualizacao)) END data
FROM MadeiraNegocio cp         
    LEFT JOIN MadeiraConversaNegocio c ON (cp.id = c.idNegocioOriginal OR cp.id = c.idNegocioResposta)
    LEFT JOIN MadeiraMensagemConversaNegocio m ON c.id = m.idConversa
WHERE cp.id = 959 AND ((cp.id = c.idNegocioOriginal AND 960 = c.idNegocioResposta) OR (960 = c.idNegocioOriginal AND cp.id = c.idNegocioResposta)) AND
    (cp.id = 959 OR 960 = cp.idNegocioOriginal) AND (m.idAutor != 4370 OR m.idAutor IS NULL)
```

As is, this query returns [null, null, null]. The second null was excepted, but not the first nor third.
What is really freaking me out is the fact that, if I remove the MAX on the first attribute, dataAtualizacao is correctly returned, with a not NULL value.

How is it possible that even though there is a value to be aggregated, MAX is returning null? Am I missing something here?

Kind regards

**EDIT**

MadeiraNegocio table:

```
id  dataRegistro    idNegocioOriginal   cancelado   dataAtualizacao dataVisualizacao    
959 2017-08-18 11:28:58 null    0   2017-08-18 15:38:16 2017-08-18 16:00:23
```

MadeiraConversaNegocio table:

```
id  idNegocioOriginal   idNegocioResposta   dataVisualizacaoOriginal    dataVisualizacaoResposta
288 959 960 2017-08-18 14:54:10 2017-08-18 17:34:17
```

MadeiraMensagemConversaNegocio

```
id  idConversa  idAutor mensagem    dataRegistro
229 288 4370    sometext    2017-08-18 16:25:02
```

Comment: What happens when you replace MAX with COUNT?

Comment: It returns 0,  and if I replace the whole select statement with "SELECT *" it doesn't return any entries either. How come when I specify the table and column a valid timestamp is returned?

Comment: We might have to see the rest of the query or your data to answer that? It doesn't really make sense as stated

Comment: I'm running just this excerpt of the query, ignoring everything else. Regarding the data, how would be a useful way to present it? I was able to find out that the last condition on the WHERE clause was making the query not return any entry, but I still don't understand why selecting just the timestamp column it actually returns a value

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Alright, I edited the question adding the relevant db structure and data, hopefully it isn't too bad to comprehend, I don't really like tabs as separators, but I thought that may be the best option

Answer (score 0):

You can try  using count() as it will always return some value or you can also try [COALSEC](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php) function.

```
select count(field1) from table where id = 1 ;
```

Comment: COUNT returns 0 for some reason, while specifying the table and column gives me a value, selecting all columns in the table also returns without any entries.